# How to delete a cloud folder but not the locally stored one?

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

I have a folder in the cloud. I want to delete it but **NOT** the folder on my hard drive.

As the storage usage shows, I think the only thing in my account is just the folder reference.

I have looked at the FAQ but can not find anything. Just highlighting the entry and pressing *Delete* does not work.

Comment: What cloud service are you using?

Comment: @Mitch Him added the *ubuntu-one* tag, so him should be using that service.

Answer (score 2):

Through the magic of stackable file systems, the files exist in the cloud, and only seem to be on your system. Copy the files to a non-cloud directory on your disk. Then, and only then, delete the cloud folder. It will vanish on your system, too.

Comment: WaltinatorThank you very much. It worked! ( I first copied it to the desktop then also to a USB stick just to be safe). The folder has about 2000 pictures and I did not want to go through the hassle of copying them from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If your folder is other than the "Ubuntu One" folder, or is no located inside it, open the Ubuntu One control panel and uncheck "sincronize locally".

If not, follow @waltinator's answer.